# Is there a way to make a Meta Function / Meta initializer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization

I wrote this little code while learning Meta classes that just registers all my class docs to a global var for all classes that have the given Meta Class:

```html
docs = {}

def register_docs(cls):
    docs[cls.__name__] = cls.__doc__

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
        cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)
        register_docs(cls)
        return cls

class RegDocs(metaclass=Meta):
    '''
    My Docs are here
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(docs)
```

`{'RegDocs': '\n    My Docs are here\n    '}`

Is there a way to do something similar in `__init__.py` or have a "Meta Function" that can do this for a flat method file? I would like to be able to access a `global` that has information about methods similar to the example below, that does some initialization on methods before being called.

```html
func_info = {}

@metafunc
def foo():
  """
  My foo docs
  """
  pass
  
print(func_info)

> {'foo':'\n  My foo docs\n '}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
func_info = {}

def metafunc(func):
    func_info[func.__name__] = func.__doc__
    return func

@metafunc
def foo():
  """
  My foo docs
  """
  pass

print(func_info)
# {'foo': '\n  My foo docs\n  '}
```

This has the advantage of [also working on classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/):

```
@metafunc
class RegDocs(metaclass=Meta):
    '''
    My Docs are here
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(func_info)
# {'foo': '\n  My foo docs\n  ', 'RegDocs': '\n    My Docs are here\n    '}
```

Comment: Thanks, follow up. If I was importing a flat file and had __init__.py import `os` and my function decorator call` os.remove("./*")` would that be triggered if someone used `import evil_package` or `from evil_package import *`? Curious about security issues with using these meta objects.

Comment: So this doesn't have anything to do with meta classes or decorators.  Whenever you `import`, you're executing a Python file.  That file can do more or less anything.